# Parallel For - Save In Database

Tags: c#, wpf, performance, parallel-processing

I'm having a lot of data to import into my database.

These data need of treatment, filtration, joint, among other things. So everything is being done with objects, carrying all tables before starting, and saving all objects to the end.

After all processing, I run the command to save. This is taking too long. I thought of practicing a different approach:

> ```
> Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
>         {
>             while (allCSV.Length % 4 != 0)
>             {
>                 Save(allCSV.FirstOrDefault());
>                 allCSV = allCSV.Skip(1).ToArray();
>             }
> ```

```
            int count1 = 0;
            int middle = allCSV.Length / 4;
            int count2 = middle;
            int count3 = middle * 2;
            int count4 = middle * 3;
            Parallel.For(0, 4, new Action<int>((i) =>
            {
                switch (i)
                {
                    case 0:
                       for (int j = 0; j < middle; j++)
                       {
                         Save(allCSV[count1]);
                         count1++;
                       }
                    break;
                    case 1:
                       for (int k = 0; k < middle; k++)
                       {
                         Save(allCSV[count2]);
                         count2++;
                       }
                    break;
                    case 2:
                       for (int l = 0; l < middle; l++)
                       {
                         Save(allCSV[count3]);
                         count3++;
                       }
                    break;
                    case 3:
                       for (int m = 0; m < middle; m++)
                       {
                         Save(allCSV[count4]);
                         count4++;
                       }
                    break;
                 }
              }
          }
```

That would be correct? What would be the best way to streamline my process?

Some considerations, the computer used is the latest generation. The database is MySQL.

The ORM used to save, it is highly simple, does not have any kind of optimizations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless you can do multiple inserts into the table(s) at one time, multi-threading the application won't help.  I ran into this problem with SQL Server.  The insert/updates were taking a long time since we were doing so many of them and they all had to be atomic so one insert/update meant the entire table got locked.  I don't know if mySQL handles table level locking any better but I doubt it.

Your best bet might be to look at a database centered solution.  Doing transactions, bulk inserts, ETL, etc might be a much better solution that writing some C# code.

Answer (score 2):

It seems like you're overcomplicating it. Wouldn't

```
Parallel.ForEach(allCsv, Save);
```

be more straightforward?

Of course, whether you'll get any performance benefit from parallelizing the operation is debatable.

Comment: It might be a problem to do so.
For example, each object has X relations. Are not symmetrical objects. If I let him control parallelism.  I may end up losing too much performance.

Comment: Parallel.ForEach will add threads dynamically if needed. Usually I limit it to environment.processorcount by supplying a ParallelOptions object with MaxDegreeOfParallelism set.